# trying to read text file using Perl

Tags: perl

I want the user to input a file name and have the program output the contents of the file.

I get 2x "Unquoted string may clash with future reserved word" and "Global  symbol $filename requires explicit package name.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print 'Enter file name: ';
my $fileName = <STDIN>;
chomp($fileName);
open(fh, $filename or die $!);
```

Also, why is file handle not a variable (actually depending on the example I've seen it a variable or not, like what I have here)?

Comment: Using `use diagnostics` in place of `use warnings` gives warnings that explain the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your problems are right here (and `$filename` vs. `$fileName`).

```
open(fh, $filename or die $!);
```

You want something more like

```
open (my $fh, '<', $filename) || die $!;
```

In the first case, the `die` condition is on `$filename`; it's equivalent to:

```
if (!$filename) { die $! }
```

But the second one is more like:

```
if (!open (my $fh, '<', $filename)) { die $! }
```

Although doing it this way (with `if (!open)`) is pointless unless you declare `$fh` with a more useful scope -- right now it's only visible inside the `if` block.

The second case implicitly covers the first case, since if `$filename` is undefined `open()` will fail with `Use of uninitialized value $filename in open`.

Comment: What difference does the die being in/out of the brackets make?

Comment: Inside, you die if `$filename` is undefined or false. Outside, you die if `open` doesn't succeed. `open` may fail even if `$filename` is undefined, so outside the parentheses is preferred.

Comment: For a person at this level in Perl, you should use your words to explain the difference, especially when there are at least three orthogonal things at play here. :)

Answer (score 5):

`$fileName` is different than `$filename` -- Perl is case sensitive!

Answer (score 4):

> I get 2x "Unquoted string may clash with future reserved word" and

`fh` should be `my $fh`

> "Global symbol $filename requires explicit package name.

`$fileName` and `$filename` are different variables. The second one hasn't be declared.

Answer (score 3):

You also asked why you sometimes see bareword filehandles (e.g.`fh`) versus scalar ones (e.g. `$fh`).  The former is deprecated.  Using declared, but otherwise undefined, scalar filehandles is called using an "indirect" filehandle.  Perl auto-vivifies (creates) a reference to the file (handle) for you.  Most importantly, as soon as the variable goes out-of-scope, and there are no other references to it, the filehandle is automatically closed and Perl's garbage collection can reap the memory used.

Comment: http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/a/readwritefiles.htm is severely out-dated

Answer (score 2):

You need the dollar sign and the correct `$fileName`:

```
open(my $fh, '<', $fileName) or die $!;
```

Here's some helpful reference: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

Comment: `open(my $fh, $fileName) or die $!;` would be better.